# Custom JPQL query in Corda for doing group by operations

Tags: jpql, corda

I have a queryable state in which I have a sender and amount fields. Is it possible to write a custom HQL or JPQL queries to get the total sum grouped by each sender.
example

```
select sender,sum(amount) from stateTable group by sender
```

If possible please let me know how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the JDBC session present in the serviceHub to add the custom JDBC query.
Please find below the reference for the same

https://docs.corda.net/api-persistence.html#jdbc-session-ref